# microdata re-occurring events

Tags: html, events, microdata

What I would like to do is add microdata to a few site's I maintain mostly small bar and grill type businesses.  What I'm looking for is an acceptable way to mark-up a re-occurring event, for example "Ladies night Thursdays 7-10.  Two for one on anything."  Am I missing something?  Everything I see requires a future date and I have not been able to find an example of an event that happens more than once.  I thought a comma separated list could work for a month at a time or so but I haven't seen anything like that either.

Comment: Well I see no one here is talking much about this either.  I've spent way to much time on this already for something I thought would be easy microdata has been a huge pain in my arse!  It would appear however that what needs to be done is to use the 'offer' vocab.  for these types of events.  But, another question.  Do you add microdata to the html tag of every page.  Say its a localBusiness website.  I've seen that it can be added to the html tag or in the head of the page which looked a little more complex.  What do you all suggest?